# How do I get a tap to register on Tizen-wearable 4.0?

Tags: c#, tizen-web-app

I am trying to setup an app on SM-R800 tizen-wearable app 4.0 (Samsung  Galaxy watch) that will display a tap when it registers in addition to displaying ambient light and ambient pressure. (This is done in C#)

I've tried using the `Window` class to try to pass my touch event arguments because it doesn't seem like the "View" class is capable of doing that according to the Tizen documentation available.

```
//using System;
//using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Linq;
//using System.Text;
// using ElmSharp; can't be used because it is redundant with Xamarin    forms namespace
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Tizen.Wearable.CircularUI.Forms;
using Tizen.Sensor;
using Tizen.NUI;

namespace TizenWearableApp6
{

    public class App : Application
    {
        LightSensor sensor;
        Label textlabel;
        PressureSensor sensor2;
        Label barometer_label;
        //Touch touch;

        public Vector2 startPos;
        public Vector2 direction;
        //Label m_Text;

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            //base.OnCreate();
            //Initialize();
        }

        public App()
        {

            /*
            Window window = Window.Instance;
            window.TouchEvent += WindowTouched;
            //touch = new Touch(); //this line has to be in a method like "public App()"


            m_Text = new Label
            {
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
            };

            void WindowTouched(object sender, Window.TouchEventArgs e)
            {
                m_Text.Text = "I have been touched!";
            } */

            if (PressureSensor.IsSupported)
            {
                sensor2 = new PressureSensor(); //instantiate HERE
                barometer_label = new Label
                {
                    HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
                };

                sensor2.Start(); //Barometer sensor
                sensor2.DataUpdated += OnDataUpdated2; //Subscribed event handler (OnDataUpdated2) to event (DataUpdated)

                void OnDataUpdated2(object sender, PressureSensorDataUpdatedEventArgs e) // event handler for humidity
                {
                    barometer_label.Text = "Ambient pressure Level: " + e.Pressure;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                barometer_label = new Label()
                {
                    HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                    Text = "Does not exist"
                };
            }

            //-----------------Light Sensor------------------------
            sensor = new LightSensor(); //"new" because I'm instantiaing a new object of the light sensor class

            textlabel = new Label
            {
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
            };

            sensor.Start(); //Light sensor
            sensor.DataUpdated += OnDataUpdated1; //Subscribed event handler (OnDataUpdated1) to event (DataUpdated)

            void OnDataUpdated1(object sender, LightSensorDataUpdatedEventArgs e) //event handler
            {
                textlabel.Text = "Light level: " + e.Level;
            }

            // The root page of your application
            MainPage = new CirclePage
            {
                Content = new StackLayout
                {

                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    Children = {
                        textlabel,
                        barometer_label,
                        //m_Text
                    }
                }
            };
        }


        /*  protected override void OnStart()
          {
              // Handle when your app starts

          } */

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

With the above code, I commented out the stuff I was trying (unsuccessfully) and just left the portions of my code that works. I expect to see real time updates of ambient light, pressure and expect a string that says "I have been touched!" each time I tap the watch.

What I actually get, (assuming I just use what I have above) is the real time update of ambient light and ambient pressure but the moment I uncomment my `Window` class stuff then I get a "Out of frame" error and if I ONLY uncomment my label `m_Text` in both the Children of the `VerticalOptions` and when I declare "Label m_Text" then I get a segmentation fault error.

Please note that some of the comments might seem arbitrary because I had left some stuff I had tried previously and does NOT necessarily mean I had EVERYTHING uncommented at one time.

Lastly, it might be good to know that I am a complete newbie in C#, Tizen, and Microsoft Visual Studio so I will definitely ask a lot of very beginner level questions.

Answer (score 1):

To start with what would have been misunderstood, there are quite a number of different APIs available when building Tizen .NET applications UI. Some of those are not documented very well so far. To name a few (what we can see in the VisualStudio new project window):

1. **[Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/)**: A rich set of cross-platform APIs available for Android, iOS, UWP, and Tizen as well.
2. **[Tizen.Wearable.CircularUI](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/.net-application/wearable-circular-ui)**: An extension of Xamarin.Forms which is only available when developing for Tizen *Wearable*s.
3. **[ElmSharp-Beta](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/csapi/api/ElmSharp.html)**: A C# wrapper of the traditional Tizen native framework (Elementary) which comes with limited support and is widely used for internal implementation.
4. **[Tizen.NUI](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/.net-application/natural-user-interface)**: A new C# GUI framework built on top of Tizen DALi (native graphics library).

So let's get back to the question. Since your project is based on **Xamarin.Forms** (and Tizen.Wearable.CircularUI), you may want to refer to [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap) from the official website to handle user gestures. For example you can simply register a *TapGestureRecognizer* instance to your *StackLayout* component as follows (instead of having to import Tizen.NUI APIs).

```cs
    var layout = new StackLayout
    {
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        Children = { textlabel, barometer_label, m_Text }
    };

    TapGestureRecognizer tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
    tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (sender, e) =>
    {
        m_Text.Text = "I have been touched!";
    };
    layout.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);

    MainPage = new CirclePage
    {
        Content = layout
    };
```

I hope it helps and enjoy developing wearable applications.